# Endianness of Android NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk

I'm working with my new app which processed captured image from cellphone camera. My phone is Nexus S, 2.3.4.

I create a ARGB_8888 Bitmap with captured data. I know the ndk image lib, but it's only support 2.2 and above. So I pass the int[] of Bitmap to NDK and found the color byte order is little-endian.

I searched the wiki and found arm architecture is bi-endian.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Bi-endian_hardware

My question is if arm is bi-endian, how to judge the byte order in specific device? Should I test the byte order every time before access the data?

Comment: I'm surprised it's necessary, doesn't bi-endianity imply that the OS would configure a common endian format across all devices? Have you come across any situation where the colour byte order is not little-endian?

Comment: Since ARMv6, you can dynamically switch the endian-ness of ARM, but iOS, Android and Windows (all flavors) use little-endian.  This does not change on different devices.

Comment: Thank you, Jodes and BitBank. It seems like I should only focus on the little-endian on Android devices.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Yes most cpus bi-endian, but most end user operating systems in use today choose to use the cpus in little-endian. Along those lines, ARM can operate in both as a convenience, its actual default after ARM 3 is little-endianess which is the endian mode it starts up in. I think one can safely assume that all Android devices are little endian, otherwise it would be extra work if different android devices were a mixture of endianess.

Because network byte order is big-endian, it can be helpful to convert any format you plan on using for data interchange to network byte order. Again, though, Mac OS X on Intel, Windows, iOS and Android are little-endian, so you might just code up structures with the native endianness and hope the next great OS you want to port data to doesn't go big-endian.

Comment: Rather, 95% of the computers you're likely to encounter are little-endian.

Comment: Android isnt about desktops or other big computers. Its about phones, tablets most of which are powered by ARM cpus.

Comment: It appears that all Android systems are little endian.

Comment: Android may be little endian, but Java is not. :/ http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html#writeShort(int)

Comment: I would say that 95% is a huge underestimate. Probably closer to 99.99999%

Answer (score 44):

Directly from my Nexus S:

```
> import java.nio.*;
> System.out.println(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
LITTLE_ENDIAN
```

There should also be some way to get the ordering in the NDK.

Answer (score 24):

[ARM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_architecture) processors (on which some Android is running) supports [both endian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bi-endian#Bi-endian_hardware) formats.

In NDK-ROOT/platforms/android-[x]/arch-arm/usr/include/machine/endian.h you can find:

```
#ifdef __ARMEB__
#define _BYTE_ORDER _BIG_ENDIAN
#else
#define _BYTE_ORDER _LITTLE_ENDIAN
#endif
```

`__ARMEB__` is defined by the gcc compiler when using the `-mbig-endian` [ARM option](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/ARM-Options.html).
Even if most Android architectures are using little endian by default you shouldn't take this for granted and for portability reasons your native code should be able to handle both endiannes.

To do that you should `#include <endian.h>` and check `BYTE_ORDER` to architecture your code properly.

Comment: Good answer, small correction: 

actually, _BYTE_ORDER is defined in NDK-ROOT/platforms/android-[x]/arch-arm/usr/include/machine/endian.h

Comment: -1. Randomly defining _ARMEB_ isn't going to make the byte order magically big endian, it'll just make the _BYTE_ORDER_ macro incorrect.

Comment: @NicholasWilson I've explicitly said you shouldn't define ARMEB

Comment: Thank you @MarkKahn for the correction. I'm not sure though if it holds true for all SDKs.

Comment: @mehy Where? Your answer suggests that defining \_ARMEB_ on the commandline will affect the endianness you get, which is false.

Comment: @NicholasWilson: I've improved the answer. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks, that's great!

Answer (score 11):

To provide very straightforward answer, here is a list:

- armeabi: LITTLE_ENDIAN
- armeabi-v7a: LITTLE_ENDIAN
- arm64-v8a: LITTLE_ENDIAN
- mips: LITTLE_ENDIAN
- mips64: LITTLE_ENDIAN
- x86: LITTLE_ENDIAN
- x86_64: LITTLE_ENDIAN

... as of Android API level 21.

Comment: Thanks, but a source would be appreciated.

Comment: @DroidCoder Extracted from Android NDK.

Comment: Where's this located in the NDK?

Answer (score 5):

```
bool isLittleEndian() {
    unsigned short word=0x0102;
    return *(char*)&word==2;
}
```

simple.

Comment: Thank you @NoAngel, but sometimes we need conditional compilation

Answer (score 0):

Android NDK has below macros which may be used to check at compile time:

```
#if defined(__LITTLE_ENDIAN_BITFIELD)
#  error "Arch is Little Endian"
#elif defined (__BIG_ENDIAN_BITFIELD)
#  error "Arch is Big Endian"
#endif
```

in your case you should assume Little-Endian and place below some-where in the Native source if any:

```
#if _BYTE_ORDER != _LITTLE_ENDIAN || defined (__BIG_ENDIAN_BITFIELD)
#  error "Big-Endian Arch is not supported"
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried with the "lxgr" answer, and I got LITTLE_ENDIAN also.

But working with C++, I read some file with this info:
**50 4B 03 04** 14 00 00 00 08 00 55 8A F4 3C 9B AA ...

I read the first 4 bytes as UnsignedLong, and I get 67324752 which (in hexa) is:

4034B50

(the first 4 bits, but reversed, as if i was working on a BIG_ENDIAN arch )

So, probably the "System.out.println(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());" reffers to how to handle them in java, but working in c++ with the NDK, you will have to check yourself, here is some code to shrink endiannes (from long readed in BIG_ENDIAN):

```
long shrinkEndian(long value){
    long result = 0;
    result += (value & 4278190080) >> 24;
    result += (value & 16711680) >> 8;
    result += (value & 65280) << 8;
    result += (value & 255) << 24;

    return result;
}
```

Comment: In little-endian, the bytes are stored reversed in memory and in files, so the behaviour above (reading `50 4B 03 04` as `0x04034B50`) is correct for **little-endian** machines, not big-endian as you incorrectly claim.