# How to pass a C String Emoji to Java via JNI

Tags: java, android, c++, java-native-interface, emoji

I am trying to pass a database value to Java via JNI :

> __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "MyApp", "c_string >>> %s", cStringValue);
>
> > **prints :** c_string >>>

```
env->SetObjectField(jPosRec, myJniPosRec->_myJavaStringValue, env->NewStringUTF(strdup(cStringValue)));
```

However, this fails without errors.

How can you go about passing special characters *(such as emojis)* to Java in JNI?

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cribbing from [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59895032/1548468) here, you can use the JNI equivalent of

```
Charset.forName("UTF-8").decode(bb).toString()
```

as follows, where each paragraph roughly implements one step, and the last sets your object field to the result:

```
jobject bb = env->NewDirectByteBuffer((void *) cStringValue, strlen(cStringValue));

jclass cls_Charset = env->FindClass("java/nio/charset/Charset");
jmethodID mid_Charset_forName = env->GetStaticMethodID(cls_Charset, "forName", "(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/nio/charset/Charset;");
jobject charset = env->CallStaticObjectMethod(cls_Charset, mid_Charset_forName, env->NewStringUTF("UTF-8"));

jmethodID mid_Charset_decode = env->GetMethodID(cls_Charset, "decode", "(Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;)Ljava/nio/CharBuffer;");
jobject cb = env->CallObjectMethod(charset, mid_Charset_decode, bb);

jclass cls_CharBuffer = env->FindClass("java/nio/CharBuffer");
jmethodID mid_CharBuffer_toString = env->GetMethodID(cls_CharBuffer, "toString", "()Ljava/lang/String;");
jstring str = env->CallObjectMethod(cb, mid_CharBuffer_toString);

env->SetObjectField(jPosRec, myJniPosRec->_myJavaStringValue, str);
```

Comment: Thank you. Works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

First off, you are leaking the memory allocated by `strdup()`. You need to pass the `char*` pointer from `strdup()` to `free()` when you are done using it. However, there is no need to call `strdup()` in this situation at all, you can pass `cStringValue` directly to JNI's `NewStringUTF()` function.

That said, JNI's [`NewStringUTF()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#wp17220) function requires the input C string to be in ["modified" UTF-8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/types.html#wp16542) format, which standard C++ knows nothing about. While it is possible to create a C string in that format, you will have to do so manually.  Since Java strings use a UTF-16 interface, and standard C++ has facilities to work with UTF-16 strings, I strongly suggest you use JNI's  [`NewString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#wp4925) function instead.

If your database code allows you to retrieve strings in UTF-16 format, then you are all set.  If not, you will have to convert the strings to UTF-16 before passing them to `NewString()` (just as you would have to convert them to "modified" UTF-8 if you continue using `NewStringUTF()`).