# JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: input is not valid Modified UTF-8: illegal start byte 0xf0

Tags: android-ndk, java-native-interface

my app crashed and the logcat shows this"" JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: input is not valid Modified UTF-8: illegal start byte 0xf0""

the logcat shows this

03-19 10:39:29.491 25489-25517/org.aitech.ai.debug A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: input is not valid Modified UTF-8: illegal start byte 0xf0
03-19 10:39:29.491 25489-25517/org.aitech.ai.debug A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]     string:

---

'ZA_SPEENA_JALLABI__YAMA_LALAI_ME_GHANAM__RANG_DE_(_BY_ARYANA_SAEED_)*(128k).mp3'
03-19 10:39:29.491 25489-25517/org.aitech.ai.debug A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]     in call to NewStringUTF
03-19 10:39:29.491 25489-25517/org.aitech.ai.debug A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]     from org.aitech.medialibrary.interfaces.media.MediaWrapper[] org.aitech.medialibrary.MedialibraryImpl.nativeGetSortedPagedAudio(int, boolean, int, int)
03-19 10:39:29.491 25489-25517/org.aitech.ai.debug A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65] "arch_disk_io_1" prio=5 tid=20 Runnable
03-19 10:39:29.491 25489-25517/org.aitech.ai.debug A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x13054160 self=0xdd476000
03-19 10:39:29.491 25489-25517/org.aitech.ai.debug A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   | sysTid=25517 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xf4923080
03-19 10:39:29.491 25489-25517/org.aitech.ai.debug A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   | state=R schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=10 stm=8 core=3 HZ=100
03-19 10:39:29.491 25489-25517/org.aitech.ai.debug A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   | stack=0xdccb7000-0xdccb9000 stackSize=1036KB
03-19 10:39:29.491 25489-25517/org.aitech.ai.debug A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   | held mutexes= "mutator lock"(shared held)
03-19 10:39:29.491 25489-25517/org.aitech.ai.debug A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #00 pc 00004e64  /system/lib/libbacktrace_libc++.so (UnwindCurrent::Unwind(unsigned int, ucontext*)+23)
03-19 10:39:29.491 25489-25517/org.aitech.ai.debug A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #01 pc 00003665  /system/lib/libbacktrace_libc++.so (Backtrace::Unwind(unsigned int, ucontext*)+8)
03-19 10:39:29.491 25489-25517/org.aitech.ai.debug A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #02 pc 0026bc55  /system/lib/libart.so (art::DumpNativeStack(std::__1::basic_ostream >&, int, char const*, art::mirror::ArtMethod*)+84)
03-19 10:39:29.491 25489-25517/org.aitech.ai.debug A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #03 pc 0024e367  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Thread::Dump(std::__1::basic_ostream >&) const+158)
03-19 10:39:29.491 25489-25517/org.aitech.ai.debug A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #04 pc 000b6d7b  /system/lib/libart.so (art::JniAbort(char const*, char const*)+610)
03-19 10:39:29.491 25489-25517/org.aitech.ai.debug A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #05 pc 000b74a1  /system/lib/libart.so (art::JniAbortF(char const*, char const*, ...)+68)
03-19 10:39:29.491 25489-25517/org.aitech.ai.debug A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #06 pc 000b9a5b  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ScopedCheck::Check(bool, char const*, ...) (.constprop.129)+922)
03-19 10:39:29.491 25489-25517/org.aitech.ai.debug A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #07 pc 000c3545  /system/lib/libart.so (art::CheckJNI::NewStringUTF(_JNIEnv*, char const*)+44)
03-19 10:39:29.491 25489-25517/org.aitech.ai.debug A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #08 pc 000bc843  /data/app/org.aitech.ai.debug-1/lib/arm/libmla.so (mediaToMediaWrapper(_JNIEnv*, fields*, std::__ndk1::shared_ptr const&)+514)
03-19 10:39:29.491 25489-25517/org.aitech.ai.debug A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #09 pc 000b27af  /data/app/org.aitech.ai.debug-1/lib/arm/libmla.so (???)
03-19 10:39:29.491 25489-25517/org.aitech.ai.debug A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #10 pc 000b28f7  /data/app/org.aitech.ai.debug-1/lib/arm/libmla.so (getPagedAudio(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, int, unsigned char, int, int)+46)
03-19 10:39:29.491 25489-25517/org.aitech.ai.debug A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #11 pc 00a7a383  /data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@org.aitech.ai.debug-1@base.apk@classes.dex (Java_org_videolan_medialibrary_MedialibraryImpl_nativeGetSortedPagedAudio__IZII+110)
03-19 10:39:29.491 25489-25517/org.aitech.ai.debug A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at org.aitech.medialibrary.MedialibraryImpl.nativeGetSortedPagedAudio(Native method)
03-19 10:39:29.491 25489-25517/org.aitech.ai.debug A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at org.aitech.medialibrary.MedialibraryImpl.getPagedAudio(MedialibraryImpl.java:194)
03-19 10:39:29.491 25489-25517/org.aitech.ai.debug A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at org.aitech.ai.providers.medialibrary.TracksProvider.getPage(TracksProvider.kt:63)
03-19 10:39:29.491 25489-25517/org.aitech.ai.debug A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at org.aitech.ai.providers.medialibrary.TracksProvider.getPage(TracksProvider.kt:33)
03-19 10:39:29.491 25489-25517/org.aitech.ai.debug A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at org.aitech.ai.providers.medialibrary.MedialibraryProvider$MLDataSource.loadInitial(MedialibraryProvider.kt:127)
03-19 10:39:29.491 25489-25517/org.aitech.ai.debug A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at androidx.paging.PositionalDataSource.dispatchLoadInitial(PositionalDataSource.java:362)
03-19 10:39:29.491 25489-25517/org.aitech.ai.debug A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at androidx.paging.TiledPagedList.(TiledPagedList.java:112)
03-19 10:39:29.491 25489-25517/org.aitech.ai.debug A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at androidx.paging.PagedList.create(PagedList.java:452)
03-19 10:39:29.491 25489-25517/org.aitech.ai.debug A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at androidx.paging.PagedList$Builder.build(PagedList.java:611)
03-19 10:39:29.491 25489-25517/org.aitech.ai.debug A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at androidx.paging.LivePagedListBuilder$1.compute(LivePagedListBuilder.java:202)
03-19 10:39:29.491 25489-25517/org.aitech.ai.debug A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at androidx.paging.LivePagedListBuilder$1.compute(LivePagedListBuilder.java:167)
03-19 10:39:29.491 25489-25517/org.aitech.ai.debug A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at androidx.lifecycle.ComputableLiveData$2.run(ComputableLiveData.java:101)
03-19 10:39:29.491 25489-25517/org.aitech.ai.debug A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
03-19 10:39:29.491 25489-25517/org.aitech.ai.debug A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
03-19 10:39:29.491 25489-25517/org.aitech.ai.debug A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
03-19 10:39:29.491 25489-25517/org.aitech.ai.debug A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65] 03-19 10:39:29.491 25489-25517/org.aitech.ai.debug A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: input is not valid Modified UTF-8: illegal start byte 0xf0
03-19 10:39:29.491 25489-25517/org.aitech.ai.debug A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]     string: 'ZA_SPEENA_JALLABI__YAMA_LALAI_ME_GHANAM__RANG_DE_(_BY_ARYANA_SAEED_)(128k).mp3'
03-19 10:39:29.491 25489-25517/org.aitech.ai.debug A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]     in call to NewStringUTF
03-19 10:39:29.491 25489-25517/org.aitech.ai.debug A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]     from org.aitech.medialibrary.interfaces.media.MediaWrapper[] org.aitech.medialibrary.MedialibraryImpl.nativeGetSortedPagedAudio(int, boolean, int, int)
03-19 10:39:29.491 25489-25517/org.aitech.ai.debug A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65] "arch_disk_io_1" prio=5 tid=20 Runnable
03-19 10:39:29.491 25489-25517/org.aitech.ai.debug A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x13054160 self=0xdd476000
03-19 10:39:29.491 25489-25517/org.aitech.ai.debug A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   | sysTid=25517 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xf4923080
03-19 10:39:29.491 25489-25517/org.aitech.ai.debug A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   | state=R schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=10 stm=8 core=3 HZ=100
03-19 10:39:29.491 25489-25517/org.aitech.ai.debug A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   | stack=0xdccb7000-0xdccb9000 stackSize=1036KB
03-19 10:39:29.491 25489-25517/org.aitech.ai.debug A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   | held mutexes= "mutator lock"(shared held)
03-19 10:39:29.491 25489-25517/org.aitech.ai.debug A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #00 pc 00004e64  /system/lib/libbacktrace_libc++.so (UnwindCurrent::Unwind(unsigned int, ucontext*)+23)
03-19 10:39:29.491 25489-25517/org.aitech.ai.debug A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #01 pc 00003665  /system/lib/libbacktrace_libc++.so (Backtrace::Unwind(unsigned int, ucontext*)+8)
03-19 10:39:29.491 25489-25517/org.aitech.ai.debug A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #02 pc 0026bc55  /system/lib/libart.so (art::DumpNativeStack(std::__1::basic_ostream >&, int, char const*, art::mirror::ArtMethod*)+84)
03-19 10:39:29.491 25489-25517/org.aitech.ai.debug A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #03 pc 0024e367  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Thread::Dump(std::__1::basic_ostream >&) const+158)
03-19 10:39:29.491 25489-25517/org.aitech.ai.debug A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #04 pc 000b6d7b  /system/lib/libart.so (art::JniAbort(char const*, char const*)+610)
03-19 10:39:29.491 25489-25517/org.aitech.ai.debug A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #05 pc 000b74a1  /system/lib/libart.so (art::JniAbortF(char const*, char const*, ...)+68)
03-19 10:39:29.491 25489-25517/org.aitech.ai.debug A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #06 pc 000b9a5b  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ScopedCheck::Check(bool, char const*, ...) (.constprop.129)+922)
03-19 10:39:29.491 25489-25517/org.aitech.ai.debug A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #07 pc 000c3545  /system/lib/libart.so (art::CheckJNI::NewStringUTF(_JNIEnv*, char const*)+44)
03-19 10:39:29.491 25489-25517/org.aitech.ai.debug A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #08 pc 000bc843  /data/app/org.aitech.ai.debug-1/lib/arm/libmla.so (mediaToMediaWrapper(_JNIEnv*, fields*, std::__ndk1::shared_ptr const&)+514)
03-19 10:39:29.491 25489-25517/org.aitech.ai.debug A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #09 pc 000b27af  /data/app/org.aitech.ai.debug-1/lib/arm/libmla.so (???)
03-19 10:39:29.491 25489-25517/org.aitech.ai.debug A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #10 pc 000b28f7  /data/app/org.aitech.ai.debug-1/lib/arm/libmla.so (getPagedAudio(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, int, unsigned char, int, int)+46)
03-19 10:39:29.491 25489-25517/org.aitech.ai.debug A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #11 pc 00a7a383  /data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@org.aitech.ai.debug-1@base.apk@classes.dex (Java_org_videolan_medialibrary_MedialibraryImpl_nativeGetSortedPagedAudio__IZII+110)
03-19 10:39:29.491 25489-25517/org.aitech.ai.debug A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at org.aitech.medialibrary.MedialibraryImpl.nativeGetSortedPagedAudio(Native method)
03-19 10:39:29.491 25489-25517/org.aitech.ai.debug A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at org.aitech.medialibrary.MedialibraryImpl.getPagedAudio(MedialibraryImpl.java:194)
03-19 10:39:29.491 25489-25517/org.aitech.ai.debug A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at org.aitech.ai.providers.medialibrary.TracksProvider.getPage(TracksProvider.kt:63)
03-19 10:39:29.491 25489-25517/org.aitech.ai.debug A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at org.aitech.ai.providers.medialibrary.TracksProvider.getPage(TracksProvider.kt:33)
03-19 10:39:29.491 25489-25517/org.aitech.ai.debug A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at org.aitech.ai.providers.medialibrary.MedialibraryProvider$MLDataSource.loadInitial(MedialibraryProvider.kt:127)
03-19 10:39:29.491 25489-25517/org.aitech.ai.debug A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at androidx.paging.PositionalDataSource.dispatchLoadInitial(PositionalDataSource.java:362)
03-19 10:39:29.491 25489-25517/org.aitech.ai.debug A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at androidx.paging.TiledPagedList.(TiledPagedList.java:112)
03-19 10:39:29.491 25489-25517/org.aitech.ai.debug A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at androidx.paging.PagedList.create(PagedList.java:452)
03-19 10:39:29.491 25489-25517/org.aitech.ai.debug A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at androidx.paging.PagedList$Builder.build(PagedList.java:611)
03-19 10:39:29.491 25489-25517/org.aitech.ai.debug A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at androidx.paging.LivePagedListBuilder$1.compute(LivePagedListBuilder.java:202)
03-19 10:39:29.491 25489-25517/org.aitech.ai.debug A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at androidx.paging.LivePagedListBuilder$1.compute(LivePagedListBuilder.java:167)
03-19 10:39:29.491 25489-25517/org.aitech.ai.debug A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at androidx.lifecycle.ComputableLiveData$2.run(ComputableLiveData.java:101)
03-19 10:39:29.491 25489-25517/org.aitech.ai.debug A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
03-19 10:39:29.491 25489-25517/org.aitech.ai.debug A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
03-19 10:39:29.491 25489-25517/org.aitech.ai.debug A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
03-19 10:39:29.491 25489-25517/org.aitech.ai.debug A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   """""""""""""'

Comment: And what is the line of code that triggers this error?

Comment: It sounds like you used `NewStringUTF` on an arbitrary binary string.

Comment: yes i have used NewStringUTF andd it cause error when there is an emoji in the file name

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The  character is U+1F609 WINKING FACE.

Its regular UTF-8 encoding is f09f9889, which matches your error.
Java expects [*Modified* UTF-8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/types.html#wp16542), however:

> Characters with code points above U+FFFF (so-called supplementary characters) are represented by separately encoding the two surrogate code units of their UTF-16 representation. Each of the surrogate code units is represented by three bytes. This means, supplementary characters are represented by six bytes, u, v, w, x, y, and z.

You cannot use `NewStringUTF` for this, you will have to manually decode from UTF-8.

Cribbing from [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59998653/how-to-pass-a-c-string-emoji-to-java-via-jni/60002045#60002045), we will do the equivalent of
`Charset.forName("UTF-8").decode(bb).toString()`:

```cpp
const char * filename = /* what you have now */;
jobject bb = env->NewDirectByteBuffer(filename, strlen(filename));

jclass cls_Charset = env->FindClass("java/nio/charset/Charset");
jmethodID mid_Charset_forName = env->GetStaticMethodID(cls_Charset, "forName", "(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/nio/charset/Charset;");
jobject charset = env->CallStaticObjectMethod(cls_Charset, mid_Charset_forName, env->NewStringUTF("UTF-8"));

jmethodID mid_Charset_decode = env->GetMethodID(cls_Charset, "decode", "(Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;)Ljava/nio/CharBuffer;");
jobject cb = env->CallObjectMethod(charset, mid_Charset_decode, bb);
env->DeleteLocalRef(bb);

jclass cls_CharBuffer = env->FindClass("java/nio/CharBuffer");
jmethodID mid_CharBuffer_toString = env->GetMethodID(cls_CharBuffer, "toString", "()Ljava/lang/String;");
jstring str = env->CallObjectMethod(cb, mid_CharBuffer_toString);
// Do something with str
```

Answer (score -1):

Facing a similar issue currently and for me was working on an android project. Before I could go deep into diagonising the problem I opted to ***INVALIDATE CACHE AND RESTART*** and yeah it worked.